# I shorted out my flasher relay, what would have been damaged?

Tags: electrical, jeep, grand-cherokee, flasher

So the other day I had to replace my flasher relay in my 2002 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo and my directionals were fine. Me being a young broke college kid decided I would try and fix the solders on my old relay and return the new part to save 80$. I accidentally soldered in a dead short by connecting the 3rd and 4th connection from the left and plugged the relay into my car and it immediately made a grinding noise when I turned the key. I took the key out and tried the new relay I had just bought and had already tried so I knew it worked and now neither my directionals nor my hazards worked. The directional lights don't blink on the dash no matter what. What could have been fried or shorted? Any ideas and input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've checked all the fuses in both panels and they are all ok not of them are blown. Is it possible a wire could have melted?

Comment: How did you check them ? visually? You should use a continuity meter as the fuse can be broken but you may not see the break...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Same exact thing happened to me. We soldered the relay, put it back in and got the same noise, quickly took it out, got a new relay, but now neither the turn signals or hazards will work. The switch itself seems fine because it is still able to control the headlights. Wondering if it could possibly be the wires that run from the switch to the relay?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//mechanics.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the supply fuse for that circuit as a first step.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Every</strike> Most electrical circuits in the car should be protected by a fuse. There are commonly two fuse panels, one under the hood with some large fuses, and one somewhere in the cabin with some smaller fuses. You can check your owners manual for the location of these panels, and an explanation of which fuses are connected to which components. If you don't have a manual, you can check the fuses one at a time to see if one of them is blown.

Comment: I think you mean "most electrical circuits are protected by a fuse", as not all are. Also, some manufacturer's put a legend of which fuse does what on the inside of the cover / lid.